# Is there a way to easily import existing AWS resources into Terraform config?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have an ongoing project that have a plenty of AWS resources deployed. Initially the engineering team managed resources manually by clicking through AWS Console.

I'm implementing an infrastructure as a code pattern by adding Terraform to the project.

The main problem I'm facing is that process of importing resources manually is error-prone and time-consuming, since IDs that need to be used in import command are not consistent and requires digging into documentation everytime.

Is there a better way of doing it? I believe it should be, since Terraform provider has access to list and read AWS resources.

Does anybody passing through the same process? How did you tackle this?

I would love to hear more options and your personal experience in this regards.

Comment: Hey Ilya, take a look at [`terraformer`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer) / [`terracognita`](https://github.com/cycloidio/terracognita)

Comment: Thanks, Ermiya! These two looks intertesting, I definetely want to try them out.

Answer (score 0):

In Terraform v1.5.0 and later, use an import block to import some resources. Here you have docs about it: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/import

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem I mentioned. I still have to look up for a documentation and looks for an ID for specific type of resource. I already have a set of aliases for running list and describe for most popular resources in order to fetch their ids without sign-in into the console. But it is till doesn't looks like a good solution

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).